# Задачка с сортировкой массива

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой массив объектов

```
var array = [

    {big: true, id="0"},
    {big: false, id="1"},
    {big: false, id="2"},
    {big: true, id="3"},
    {big: false, id="4"},
    {big: false, id="5"},
    {big: true, id="6"},
    {big: false, id="7"},
    {big: false, id="8"},
    {big: false, id="9"},
    {big: false, id="10"},
    {big: false, id="11"},
    {big: true, id="12"},
    {big: true, id="13"},
    {big: true, id="14"}

];
```

Нужно отсортировать его так чтобы объекты с `big: true` были в отдельном массиве, а объекты с `big: false` были в массиве по четыре ( если встречается объект с `big: false`, то искать после него ещё три таких объекта и добавлять в массив ).

На выходе нужно иметь такой многомерный массив:

```
[
  [{
    big: true,
    id = "0"
  }],
  [{
    big: false,
    id = "1"
  }, {
    big: false,
    id = "2"
  }, {
    big: false,
    id = "4"
  }, {
    big: false,
    id = "5"
  }],
  [{
    big: true,
    id = "3"
  }],
  [{
    big: true,
    id = "6"
  }],
  [{
    big: false,
    id = "7"
  }, {
    big: false,
    id = "8"
  }, {
    big: false,
    id = "9"
  }, {
    big: false,
    id = "10"
  }],
  [{
    big: false,
    id = "11"
  }],
  [{
    big: true,
    id = "12"
  }],
  [{
    big: true,
    id = "13"
  }],
  [{
    big: true,
    id = "14"
  }]
]
```

Comment: у тебя в результате дважды используется элемент с id="1"

Comment: Ну классно. И что, совсем никаких соображений, как это сделать?

Comment: @Grundy Да, это была опечатка, поправил.

Comment: @Igor была идея `splice`'ом вырезать из массива, также была идея сохранять нужные индексы и потом отдельной функцией делать slice из массива, но все эти идеи показались глупые, при splice теряется индексация в итерации массива, а вторая идея просто глупая которую я не довёл до конца, поэтому и сказать нечего не могу по ней.
Решение должны быть лёгким, и на поверхности, я его просто не вижу.

Comment: Зачем что-то вырезать из массива? Все равно ведь результатом обработки будет новый массив. Заведите этот новый массив и идите в цикле по старому массиву, добавляя его элементы в новый нужным образом. Кроме того, Вам понадобится ссылка на текущий массив, куда добавлять `false` элементы, пока их там не станет четыре.

Comment: @Igor В таком случае мне нужна проверка есть ли объект в массиве, да?Как это сделать?

Comment: Какой объект? Такой проверки Вам не понадобится.

Comment: @Igor Ведь в массив я буду пушить элементы которые в будущем буду тоже итерировать ( три элемента после совпадения ).

Comment: Совпадения чего? Давайте, начинайте писать цикл, где Вы идете по элементам старого массива.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51540/discussion-between-kardanx-and-igor).

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Перенес из чата совместное творчество.

```js
var array = [
    {big: true, id: "0"},
    {big: false, id: "1"},
    {big: false, id: "2"},
    {big: true, id: "3"},
    {big: false, id: "4"},
    {big: false, id: "5"},
    {big: true, id: "6"},
    {big: false, id: "7"},
    {big: false, id: "8"},
    {big: false, id: "9"},
    {big: false, id: "10"},
    {big: false, id: "11"},
    {big: true, id: "12"},
    {big: true, id: "13"},
    {big: true, id: "14"}
];

var result = [];
var falseArray = null;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if (array[i].big) {
    result.push([array[i]]);
  } else {
    if (falseArray == null || falseArray.length == 4) {
      result.push(falseArray = [array[i]]);
    } else {
      falseArray.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
    {big: true, id: "0"},
    {big: false, id: "1"},
    {big: false, id: "2"},
    {big: true, id: "3"},
    {big: false, id: "4"},
    {big: false, id: "5"},
    {big: true, id: "6"},
    {big: false, id: "7"},
    {big: false, id: "8"},
    {big: false, id: "9"},
    {big: false, id: "10"},
    {big: false, id: "11"},
    {big: true, id: "12"},
    {big: true, id: "13"},
    {big: true, id: "14"}
];

var res = [];
var falseArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var obj = array[i];
  if (obj.big)
    res.push(obj);
  else {
    falseArr.push(obj);
    if (falseArr.length == 4) {
      res.push(falseArr);
      falseArr  = [];
    }
  }
}
if (falseArr.length > 0)
  res.push(falseArr);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```